# Pseudocode vertical lines

Tags: pseudocode

How can I insert this kind of pseudo code in latex?

[image]

Comment: welcome! What have you done so far? in general: you could use the `algorithm`-package to get this kind of result.

Answer (score 1):

The [algorithm2e](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) package has a `vlined` option wich does exactly what you need (you can also call `\SetAlgoVLined` at the beginning of each `algorithm` environment). Read the documentation to learn how to use the package.
See also [the relevant chapter of the LaTeX WikiBook.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms)